# How can I set up my project hierarchy in QtCreator?

Tags: qt-creator, subdirectory

I'm quite new to QtCreator, so perhaps I left my heart in eclipse-ville, but I can't for the life of me understand how I should be setting up a project hierarchy in QtCreator.  I understand there is an option to create a kind of root project and then from there add sub-projects to it, which makes sense but it leaves me wondering whether or not this is necessary at the time of creating the project, e.g. can I just create a library in one project and reference it later by another project?

I've tried setting up a blanket type of project by creating a new subdirs project and then adding the main program as a subproject, but then how should I add my library project?

Ideally, I'd like to create one project as the main application and reference another project as a library.  Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation of Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/index.html) contains two sections that may help you find the answers to your questions:

- [Adding Subprojects to Projects](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html#adding-subprojects-to-projects)
- [Adding Libraries to Projects](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html)

EDIT:
You can find a really simple sample project here: [QtSymbianDllExample](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/13361/QtSymbianDllExample.zip). "It is intended to demonstrate how to create and use a DLL with Qt on the Symbian platform". It is a sample for Symbian development but that is irrelevant now, I do not have a Symbian phone. What is important is that it contains a root project (QtSymbianDllExample\qtssymbiandllexample.pro) and two subprojects (QtSymbianDllExample\qtenginedll\qtenginedll.pro, QtSymbianDllExample\testui_simpledllengine\testui_simpledllengine.pro) which you can examine and compare to you projects. I have checked that I can build the root project by doing the following steps:

1. Download and install the Windows Offline Installer from http://www.qt.io/download/
2. Download and extract QtSymbianDllExample.zip
3. Run Qt Creator
4. File / Open File or Project... Select qtssymbiandllexample.pro
5. Build / Run qmake
6. Build / Build project "qtsymbiandllexample"

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've seen these pages, but I'm still a little confused.  If I start two separate projects, say one should used as a library and one for the main program, can I combine these two using a subdirs project?  I've seen the option to import existing projects, which I have done.  I've created a subdirs project and then imported the two existing projects but when I attempt to build the subdirs project, no build process starts.  I can still build the projects separately though.  Really, I can build the library, just not the main code that uses the library.  What am I missing?

Comment: That's exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I realize this is pretty old.